# Altering multiple features of columns in a sql database, at the same time

Tags: mysql, database

I am fairly new to sql so I have come upon a situation that most of you have probably seen.

While working on making a database more effective. I will eventually transfer the db from MS Access/Alpha 5 Anywhere to MySQL but, first, I am changing some columns' size, type, name as well as assigning foreign keys. Some columns necessitate only one change, others necessitate multiple changes.

In order to minimize the time it will take for these changes to take place on the production version, I would like to have changes done with the smallest number of statements.

As an example, is it possible to have one statement like this

```
ALTER TABLE "tablename"
ALTER COLUMN "columnname1" datatype
CHANGE "columnname1" "new_columnname1"
DROP ("columnname2", "columnname3");
```

instead of three statements like this

```
ALTER TABLE "tablename"
ALTER COLUMN "columnname1" datatype;

ALTER TABLE "tablename"
CHANGE "columnname1" "new_columnname1";

ALTER TABLE "tablename"
DROP ("columnname2", "columnname3");
```

If this is not possible, what is the correct way of achieving my goal?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Why do you have to ask???  Why don't you just try it???

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE can do multiple table alterations in one statement, but MODIFY COLUMN can only work on one column at a time, so you need to specify MODIFY COLUMN for each column you want to change:

ALTER TABLE webstore.Store
  MODIFY COLUMN ShortName VARCHAR(100),
  MODIFY COLUMN UrlShort VARCHAR(100);